# Java Scanner keep asking for input until variable is a double or int, or empty, at which point is given default value

Tags: java

here is the pseudo for what im asking

```
1. Take value
2. is value double or int?
3. if so, continue in program
4. else
5. is value empty?
6. if value empty; value=0.08
7. else
8. at this stage, value is not an empty valid, or a valid double or valid int
9. user did it wrong, prompt error
10. jump to step one take value
```

So to me this is pretty complicated, im new to this.

Ive been trying to impliment it like so;

```
while ( costscan.hasNext() )
  {
    double costperkm = costscan.nextDouble();
    if (costperkm=double){
      System.out.println("Value is double");
      System.out.println("FUEL COST SAVED ");
    }
    else {
            if(costperkm=null){
               costperkm=0.08;
          }
            else{

                }
    System.out.println("FUEL COST SAVED ");
         }
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.print("\n");
  }
```

My code above is the result of just playing about so at this stage it may not even make sense anymore. Hope someone can help, thanks.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: Don't use a specific loop like that. Use a more generic like `while(costscan.hasNext())` and then use ifs for each of your conditions.

Comment: @JustinJasmann My musings of the idea don't work, I think I have implemented it wrong

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Ill give that a try now, so just without the ! in place?

Comment: @Kieronboz Yeah, notice this method will return true if it finds a complete token, this can be a string, boolean, double, etc. You can then use your `hasDouble()` to check what it is. This way you can loop forever while there are tokens remaining in the scanner.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, ive implemented the following, see edit in post. Only problem is i cant use null to check for an empty scan.

Comment: @Kieronboz When you do things like `nextDouble()`, you are guaranteed to have a double, you don't need to check it.

Comment: So what happens if they type tentacle instead of 0.09 @SotiriosDelimanolis, this is my confusion lol.

Comment: @Kieronboz Try it. The javadoc says _Throws InputMismatchException - if the next token does not match the Float regular expression, or is out of range_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with `hasNextDouble` and `nextDouble` is that as long as the user just presses enter, they will both keep asking for input.

If you want to use a default value when the user simply presses enter, you should rather use `Scanner.nextLine` combined with `Double.parseDouble`, since `nextLine` is the only next-method that accepts empty input.

Here's a possible solution:

```
String input;
while(true) {
    input = costscan.nextLine();
    if(input.isEmpty()) {
        input = "0.08";
        break;
    }
    if(isParseable(input)) {
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("ENTER ONLY NUMBERS [DEFAULT 0.08]");
}
double costperkm = Double.parseDouble(input);
```

The method `isParseable` looks like this:

```
private static boolean isParseable(String str) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        return true;
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, so the isparseable is a seperate method I should use..

I should of thought to just do it as a string then parse, silly me, thanks very much for your help!